# Encoding issue using pd.read_csv() to read csv file in S3 location

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, boto3

**Problem:** I am getting an encoding error while trying to use pd.read_csv() to read a CSV file in an S3 location.

Below is my code:

```
 # parameters
 s3_bucket = 'my_bucket'
 s3_key = 'my_key'

 # create s3 client
 s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

 # create s3 object
 obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=s3_key)
   
 # read csv file from s3
 df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'], encoding='cp1252')
```

But this is the error I get:
**'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte**

I don't understand why I am getting the encoding error when I am specifying the encoding to be 'cp1252'. By the way, 'cp1252' is the encoding I found for my csv file.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into the [boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object) and the `get_object()` method returns a `StreamBody`. The pandas method `read_csv()` takes a path, file, buffer and so on as input ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)).

Therefore, I think you have to convert the object body first. This can be done with Python's `io` module ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO)). The following code should fix your problem:

```
obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=s3_key)
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))
```

***Explanation:*** Pandas states in the doc:

> By file-like object, we refer to objects with a read() method, such as a file handle (e.g. via builtin open function) or StringIO.

This is fulfilled by giving the `StreamBody` to `io.BytesIO` from which you can read the bytes of your file.

Comment: df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()), encoding='cp1252') - Thank you, no more error but I tried this and for some reason I am getting an empty df when I print(df). My csv file is not empty.

Comment: You're welcome! Can you check if length of `io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()` is zero?

Comment: I am getting '80' using:  bio = io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read())                             
    print(sys.getsizeof(bio))

Comment: What is the output of `print(bio.decode("utf-8"))`? or  `print(bio.decode("cp1252"))`? With this the bytes should be converted to a string and you should see the data.

Comment: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'decode' - This is the error msg I get.

Comment: So, I created my own example and am now wondering why your size is only 80? Is your file very small? Are you able to share your file?