# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 1: invalid start byte

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, encoding

I have files that need to be read using unicode_escape encoding, trying to read files from an s3 bucket with the code:

```
for file in files:
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file)
    data = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'], encoding='unicode_escape')
```

I'm presented with the error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 1: invalid start byte

I'm not understanding the error, shouldn't it be using unicode_escape instead of 'utf-8'?

Tested locally and the file reads normally
data = pd.read_csv(path, encoding='unicode_escape')

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68385385/encoding-issue-using-pd-read-csv-to-read-csv-file-in-s3-location